# Recursive feature elimination with cross validation and random forest classification: I cannot interpret the result

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, feature-selection, random-forest

I ran an expirement with my dataset and using the recursive feature elimination with cross validation and random forest classification in a binary classification problem. I came up with this result:

[image]

I cannot understand that this is a problematic situation but I really cannot interpret the result. What exactly those flunctuations mean about my dataset or the method?

Comment: What size is your data set? Is data(Y-label) balanced? What is the random forest inner tree spec(max_depth, min_split, etc..)?

Comment: Try multiple runs of CV to average out the variability and see if the curve becomes more smooth.